# no path returned when too much hops

Tags: neo4j

Let's say we have this graph.

[image]

We can find the shortest path from node 51 to no node 54 by writing this cypher query

[image]

```
match p=shortestPath((a:Intersection{id:51})-[r*0..20]-(b:Intersection{id:54}))
return p
```

[image]

So it works well, but why **it can't find paths that are far**? Like from node 51 to node 5?

[image]

Comment: What about an example of input data (query for creating nodes and relationships) on which to repeat the mistake?

Comment: I would say, because thre is no path

Comment: @alacambra how about (51)-(52)-(53)-(54)-(68)-(5)? It should be seen by neo4j right?

Comment: Yes it should definitely be. As @stdob-- suggested, it would be nice to have a data extract in order to test the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved. Issue was, node 5 doesn't contain the property 'id'.